# Conditional probability - formula validity over different sample spaces

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Is the conditional probability formula $P(B\mid A) =\frac{ P(B\cap A) }{ P(A)}$ always true? What if the sample space is non-uniform?

Comment: $P(B | A) =\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$ is a *definition*, not a formula. You don't see $P(B | A)$ being defined as something else, and then that being proved equal to $\frac{P(B \cap A) }{P(A)}$. In particular, being a definition it very much holds in non-uniform situations, but is defined only when $P(A)$ is *non-zero*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is always true because the conditional probability of B given A is defined this way. Although, it exists only if $P(A)\neq0$(that is quite obvious because if A can't occur, then it doesn't make sense to find the probability of an event given that A has already occurred).